What is the workflow when working with CMake, Visual Studio, and dependencies?
I am using CMake and the generator for Visual Studio.
My code has several dependencies. Let's say I need a DLL not built by my project.
My usual workflow would be to create a build directory inside my project directory, and from there, to call CMake to build my project. The problem is I need the DLL beside my produced executable so that I can run it.
Then, two solutions :

using file(COPY...) or similar function, and run my project from somewhere in the build directory ;
adding an install() command for the DLL, building the project, installing the projet, and running it from the installation directory.

If I choose the first one, I'll have anyway also adopt the second one, in order to release the project. So I would have to add instruction to copy et install. But if I choose only second first one, I won't be able to debug.
I can install my projet, then set the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY property to the installation directory, but I guess it is dirty...
What should I do ?

Whatever CMake build task method you use the key is to copy the debug dlls to the bin/Debug folder and the Release dlls to the bin/Release folder.
